# How to connect AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Its really fanny question but I wanted to know about this. So question is, I have successfully created one AWS account and now I want to connect with this account without EC2 launch.

is it possible using AWS key? If yes, can someone help on this?
Reason I want to do this , because I want to launch my first EC2 instance using ansible provisioning.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question i couldn't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is so I'll provide a broad answer.

Here are the different ways of interaction with AWS

- The AWS root account (email / password) that allows you to connect to the [AWS console](http://console.aws.amazon.com/) with full access over your AWS account
- [AWS IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html) that allows you to give specific restricted access to your AWS account. IAM users can either connect to the AWS console or programmatically with API keys
- SSH Login to EC2 instances you created directly or with a managed service like ECS,EKS,Beanstalk...

You can find additional information on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html).

What I would recommend if you want to manage everyting in ansible (long live [infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code)) is to manage the EC2 lifecyle through [ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code). You only need to provide API keys of an IAM user that as sufficient access in AWS in order to create an EC2 with ansible. You can then provision the created EC2 with ansible too.

Comment: Hi Quentin, as you explained in your answer I know all three points. First two point just open the amazon console and connect with registered email or any user account.  But my question is, Is it possible to connect with SSH client with launching EC2 instance. Can I connect with user root account/user account from SSH client. Reason for this I want to launch my first EC2 instance with some provisioning tool.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand the question, you want to make API calls to AWS from an EC2 instance or from your own local computer?

Comment: From my local computer using SSH client putty.